# RabbitMQ default x-expires argument for all x-message-ttl queues

Tags: rabbitmq

I make different messages with different `x-message-ttl` arguments. Each of this messages create new queue like 
`enqueue.notifications.notifications.5000.x.delay`
and I want to delete this queue after finish working with this queue. 
Can I set in RabbitMQ config, when if I push message with `x-message-ttl` argument automatically set argument `x-expires`? Or maybe it can be something which deletes all delayed queue after it finishes?

Answer (score 0):

Any way you can't be sure that the queue with delay you need is exists.
So you have to ensure that the queue exists by declaring it and during queue declaration you can set `x-expires` property according to your delay

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But I think maybe it possible to set `x-expires` property for all queues with `x-message-ttl` property by default in RabbitMQ config. Without changing app code.

Comment: Check please this page - https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html may be it is what are you looking for.